# PropTypes for functions being passed down

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

Given the code below, how do I set up proptypes for name,label, and onChange?

My current proptypes don't seem to work.

```
function FilterCheckbox(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <FormControlLabel
                control={
                    <Checkbox
                        onChange={props.bpmHandler ? props.bpmHandler : props.genreHandler}
                    />
                }
                name={props.name}
                label={props.label}
            />
            <p>name :{props.name}</p>
        </div>
    )
}

FormControlLabel.PropTypes = {
    control:PropTypes.shape({
        name:PropTypes.number,
        label:PropTypes.string
    })
}

export default FilterCheckbox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code as you present it, it seems that `FormControlLabel` is a component defined somewhere else. So first things first, its prop types should be where the component is defined, and I'm assuming would look something like this:

```
FormControlLabel.propTypes = {
  control: PropTypes.element,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
}
```

Then you have a `Checkbox` component that too should have its prop types defined where the component itself is defined. They probably look something like this:

```
Checkbox.propTypes = {
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
}
```

And now, in the file you're presenting, you are defining `FilterCheckbox` and you want it to receive props suited for both `FormControlLabel` and `Checkbox`. So I'd do it like this:

```
FilterCheckbox.propTypes = {
  name: FormControlLabel.propTypes.name,
  label: FormControlLabel.propTypes.label,
  bpmHandler: Checkbox.propTypes.onChange,
  genreHandler: Checkbox.propTypes.onChange,
}
```

And if you don't have access to the prop types of neither `Checkbox` nor `FormControlLabel` (meaning that you can't change the files where they are declared, and where they are declared omitted to add prop types). You can still write prop types for `FilterCheckbox` based on how you intend to use it anyway:

```
FilterCheckbox.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  label: PropTypes.string,
  bpmHandler: PropTypes.func,
  genreHandler: PropTypes.func,
}
```

---

PS: just in case this is another thing that was causing you trouble, it's `MyComponent.propTypes` and not `MyComponent.PropTypes`.

Comment: So my Checkbox and FormControlLabel are from material-ui and not a component that I exported. Is there a way to extend proptypes to material-ui files?

Comment: @ChazLee I added a paragraph to my answer for this case.

Comment: wow, thank you so much. I could have sworn I tried your last block of code but maybe it was the PropTypes erroring instead of propTypes.....